# How to create a XML file in azure storage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage

I'm new to Azure storage.I want to create a container and also a blob(XML file or whatever) in it. Here is the code for creating a container but I'm having trouble how to create XML (not upload form local).

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("XXXXXXXX");

        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Anyone can provide some code example would be great!!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are done with the above code to get reference of a Container, do the below:

```
//Create reference to a Blob that May or Maynot exist under the container
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("something.xml");
// Create or overwrite the "something.xml" blob with contents from a string

            string s = "your XML";
            await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(s);
```

Comment: Also do u need to create the xml something like blob.CreateIfNotExists();?

Comment: not really. i use the above code to create new HTML files from my Controller in MVC. i am not aware of such blob.CreateIfNotExists()